# Referencing images in a Rails app (Heroku deployment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, heroku, src

I'm currently having a slight problem referencing images in a Rails app which is then deployed to Heroku.

I have an image in the following path relative to the app:

```
app/assets/images/some-image.png
```

And I have referenced it in the HTML correctly (as far as I am aware):

```
<div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
   <img src="/assets/some-image.png" height="67"/><!-- **IMAGE SOURCE LINK** -->
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainNav">
       <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="scroll-link">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#introText" class="scroll-link">APR</a></li>
       <li><a href="#initiatives" class="scroll-link">Initiatives</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Yet, this is what is displayed:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html):

```
<%= image_tag "some-image.png", height: "67" %>
```

Comment: Will try this now. How would I include the width styling attribute?

Comment: from the API guide: image_tag("icon.png", size: "16x10", alt: "Edit Entry") or image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", height: '32', width: '32')

Comment: Could you give me a full working answer. Want to make sure I get the syntax right.

Comment: <%= image_tag("some-image.png", height: 67) %>

Comment: I think we are getting closer, but I'm still getting the ? within a box. The above answer generated the image but obviously not at the right height...

Comment: could you paste the <img> tag from generated html?

Comment: it's working now. I needed to write: <%= image_tag("some-image.png", height: "67") %> Just a minor omission. If you edit your answer to include the height attribute I will accept. :) Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy to heroku, your assets will get compiled with a unique digest so you can't hard-code the reference to `/assets/some-image.png`. Check out "[Rails Asset Pipeline on Heroku Cedar](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)".

You will need to use some helper functions so the image path is correctly resolved, like `image_path('my_image.png')`. See "[ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html)" or "[Asset Tag Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#asset-tag-helpers)".

Comment: Hi Derek, the answer below works, using the image_tag. My next question is to ask how to include the height attribute....

Comment: This link has a bunch of examples on how to do that. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html